# Bind Duration object with form fields

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have class with field of type Duration:

```
class MyEntity{

private Duration duration;
//getters, setters
}
```

Now in my thymeleaf template I want to have form with Hours, Minutes and Seconds:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${entity}">
     <input type="number" th:field="???" min="0" />
     <input type="number" th:field="???" min="0" max="59" />
     <input type="number" th:field="???" min="0" max="59" />
</form>
```

In my controller I would like to have something like:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveTime(@ModelAttribute MyEntity entity) {
    timeRepo.save(timeData);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Is it possible with thymeleaf to bind model that has something more than just strings and numbers but also another object types or I have to create DTO and care by myself about wrapping/unwrapping the data?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a converter, this link may help you if this notion is new for you:

[Spring MVC - Binding Java Backing Objects with Custom Converters](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-custom-converter/)